# Please help me with a sentence in Past and Present Perfect Continuous tenses

Tags: tense, grammaticality

I was reading my diary, and in one of the pages, there was a sentence:

> I have been using Chrome happily until recently I was told that
>   Chrome kept sending my private photos back to their headquarter
>   without my consent.

I think I should change the tense, "I have been using Chrome happily",
to "I had been using Chrome happily",
because the clause, "until recently I was told that Chrome..."
can not happen before "I have been using Chrome happily". 
Am I right?

Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: You're probably overanalysing things. Most native speakers probably wouldn't notice (or care) which form you used. But idiomatically I think both versions are a bit "wordy". I'd probably have written *I **was** using Chrome [quite] happily until **I was recently** told that...* Or even more likely, *I was quite happily using Chrome until...*, if the implication was that I didn't use Chrome at all after that (as opposed to continuing to use it, but no longer "happily").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was once told that the *past perfect continuous* is not widely used. Native speakers prefer the *past continuous*, for instance. Is this true?

Comment: The case is closed to : `I have been waiting...` and `I am waiting...`

Comment: As I read it, "using Chrome happily *until recently*" indicates you are no longer using it. Therefore I would use *had been*. Or use *was* as @FumbleFingers pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> **I have been using Chrome
>
>   I had been using Chrome
>
>   I was using Chrome**

are all correct and can be used, the reason is because the rest of your sentence anchors the time in the **past**

> **until recently**

though we don't know until how recently in the past.

the slight problem with your sentence is the **conjunction**, there is none

> **when** I was told

would help your sentence be smoother

> I have been using Chrome happily until recently **when** I was told...

Answer (score 2):

> I have been using Chrome happily until recently I was told that Chrome
>   kept sending my private photos back to their headquarter without my
>   consent.

Both continuous:

past perfect:

I'd been using Chrome happily until I was told that Chrome sends my private photos back to their headquarters without my consent.

past:

I was using Chrome happily until I found out that it sends my private photos back to their headquarters without my consent.

**Recently** should  go in the *until*-clause:

... until I was told recently ...

... until I found out recently...